# Error :The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to add a product to my cart but I receive this error:

> 'The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be
> used for operations that require a connection'

I have created a ViewModel for my view ShoppingCart as follow:

```
 public class ShoppingCartViewModels
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Product product{ get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Product is an Entity Model. I try to add a product to my cart with this action:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int pid)
        {      
            var product = db.Product.Find(pid);
            List<ShoppingCartViewModels> productsList = new List<ShoppingCartViewModels>();
            productsList.Add(new ShoppingCartViewModels { product = product, quantity = 1 });
            Session["shoppingcart"] = productsList;

            return RedirectToAction("ShoppingCart");
        }

public ActionResult ShoppingCart()
        {
            int totalPrice = 0;
            List<ShoppingCartViewModels> productsList = new List<ShoppingCartViewModels>();
            if (Session["shoppingcart"] != null)
            {
                productsList = Session["shoppingcart"] as List<ShoppingCartViewModels>;       
            }            

            return View(productsList);
        }
```

But in the ShoppingCart View I receive the mentioned error.

[image]

Comment: Does `Product` have any relations that need to be lazy-loaded? When the view is getting rendered the DbContext is already disposed. You need to use eager (with `Include`) or explicit loading to load any related entities in the action itself

Comment: There is a related entity, I changed my query to this:                                                   "var product = db.Product.Include(p => p.SubGroup2).Where(x=>x.ID==pid).FirstOrDefault(); " but result is still the same!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you, you were right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was because I used the related Entities to Product class in my Url.Action.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="cart-table-tr">

            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Products",
                            new { group=item.product.SubGroup2.SubGroup.GroupID,
                                subgroup =item.product.SubGroup2.SubGroupID, subgroup2=item.product.SubGroup2ID,
                                id =item.product.ID,productname=item.product.Name.Replace(" ","-")})">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.product.Name)</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.product.Price)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Products",
                            new { group=item.product.SubGroup2.SubGroup.GroupID,
                                subgroup =item.product.SubGroup2.SubGroupID, subgroup2=item.product.SubGroup2ID,
                                id =item.product.ID,productname=item.product.Name.Replace(" ","-")})"><img class="img-responsive img-cart" src="../../../@item.product.Image" /></a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("IncreaseQuantity","Products", new { pid = item.product.ID })" class="cart-links">+</a>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)
                                <a href="@Url.Action("DecreaseQuantity","Products", new { pid = item.product.ID })" class="cart-links">-</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DeleteItemFromCart", "Products", new { pid = item.product.ID }, new { @class = "delete-cart" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

So I changed my Url.Action to the following:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Products", new { id =item.product.ID})">
```